# only instance of a python 3.7 application run

Tags: python-3.7

I want to make my application by Python 3.7 run just in only one instance.

I have tried the code bellow codes but I didnt succed.

````
import psutil
import time

procs = [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if 'python.exe' in p.name() and __file__ in p.cmdline()]
if len(procs) > 1:
    print('Process is already running...')
    sys.exit(1)


for i in range(10):
    print('Running...')
    time.sleep(2)```
````

Comment: Many people create a file in "/var/run" with a unique name and write out the process id of the program into it. Then if the file exists, warn the user and refuse to run.

Comment: A common approach to solve this is a "lock file". There are many different variants using exclusive locks, pid files, time based locks etc. Exclusive file locks are usually the easiest to use, since they don't require manual cleanup. 

Since implementations are OS specific, I'd suggest looking for a platform agnostic locking package on PyPI.